# Close tab without clicking on X?

Tags: keyboard, magic-trackpad, tabs

I'm using a 2012 Retina Mac Book Pro running OS X 10.7.5. I am a Windows power user and an OS X neophyte.

Many of the keyboard and mouse shortcuts I know in Windows have functional equivalents in OS X. A feature that I find particularly useful in Windows is the ability to middle-click to close tabs (works across Firefox, Chrome, Visual Studio). This saves a user from having to click explicitly on a tab's "X" icon.

Is there a magic trackpad click equivalent to middle-clicking a Windows mouse?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The middle click to close tab functionality isn't really a common OS X UI pattern. The standard keyboard shortcut for closing a tab is <kbd>command ⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (which will also close non-tabbed windows, or windows with only one open tab).

If you really want a Magic Trackpad gesture for closing tabs, you could use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to map a gesture to ⌘W, but it would still be a bit limited, in that it would only close the currently active tab. I suppose you could use a combination of programs to make a macro that would perform a click to switch to the tab under your mouse, then close it, but it's still a bit hacky.

Comment: I was aware of the keyboard command but was hoping for a trackpad equivalent, but thanks for the tip on BetterTouchTool.